# Which "pilotless aircraft" did the authors of the 1944 Chicago convention have in mind?

Tags: aviation-history, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, icao

The Convention on International Civil Aviation (a.k.a. the "Chicago convention"), includes right from its first version, signed in 1944, an article about "pilotless aircraft". The article in question reads:

> Pilotless aircraft
>
> Article 8
>
> No aircraft capable of being flown without a pilot shall be flown
> without a pilot over the territory of a contracting State without
> special authorization by that State and in accordance with the terms
> of such authorization. Each contracting State undertakes to insure
> that the flight of such aircraft without a pilot in regions open to
> civil aircraft shall be so controlled as to obviate danger to civil
> aircraft.

The original text is available [here](http://www.icao.int/publications/pages/doc7300.aspx).

I would guess that language like that (which it takes time and effort to produce) will not get included in an international treaty without a reason.

So the question is, which aircraft did the authors of article 8 have in mind in 1944?

Comment: The only pilotless aircraft I can recall from that era were barrage balloons, but those are tethered and don't actually navigate, so I doubt that's what they had in mind. I would expect they were simply anticipating the foreseeable.

Comment: The V1 was from that timeframe.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-1_flying_bomb

Comment: The US armed forces began experimenting with "drones" in the 1930s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_unmanned_aerial_vehicles. While many hobbyists detest the use of the term "drone" to describe radio controlled aircraft the term "drone" as applied to unmanned aircraft originated with the early US Navy research in the 30s and 40s. They mostly ended up being used for target practice but at least two programs were designed to develop pilotless kamikaze aircraft (one piloted remotely by TV signal and one piloted by pigeons)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the article says that

> No aircraft capable of being **flown without a pilot**

At that point of time there were a number of radio controlled aircraft which could be flown without a pilot *on board* (for example, the [RP series aircraft](http://www.ctie.monash.edu.au/hargrave/rpav_radioplane.html) and [OQ-2 Target drone](http://www.ctie.monash.edu.au/hargrave/rpav_radioplane2.html), of which thousands were made). The authors of convention most probably had these in mind when they frame the article 8.

This [ICAO document on Unmanned Aircraft Systems](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/UAS/Documents/Circular%20328_en.pdf) also points in the same direction:

> 4.3  Article  8  details  conditions  for  operating  a  “pilotless”  aircraft  over  the  territory  of  a  contracting  State.  To  understand  he  implications  of  this  Article  and  its  inclusion  from  the  Paris  convention  of  1919  (Article  15)  into  the  Chicago  Convention  of  1944,  the  intent  of  the  drafters  must  be  considered.  Remote-control  and  uncontrolled  aircraft  were in existence at the time, operated by both civil and military entities. “[A]ircraft flown without a pilot” **therefore refers to  the  situation  where  there  is  no  pilot  on  board  the  aircraft**.  As  a  consequence,  any  RPA  is  a  “pilotless”  aircraft,  consistent with the intent of the drafters of Article 8.

(emphasis mine). So, the authors of the 1944 Chicago convention most probably had radio controlled aircraft in mind.